# break program when user enters specific string into input

Tags: java, string, break, do-while

I want to make it so that the user inputs some string, and the program takes console input until user types "/done".. so here's how it would work:

1. print to user: enter your string
2. user enters: hello eclipse.

hi test blah blah

bla 
                    456 
                  testmore              /done

As soon as user enters /done within any string of any size, the program breaks. The program would NOT end if you hit "enter" key. It would only end if you type in /done.. How I setup my program so far:

```
Scanner 123 = new Scanner(System.in);
string input = "";
System.out.println("Enter your string: ");

do {
    input = 123.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Rest of program here..");
}

while (!input.equals("/done"));
```

I tried putting under while loop there something like below but I don't think I am doing it right.

```
while (!input.equals("/done"));
    if input.equals("/done");
    break;
}
```

I understand that with a do-while loop, it continues as long as boolean in while is false. So for my program, program takes inputs until user types in /done so boolean is false until string /done in inputted. Then according to the logic above, the program breaks as soon as input equals "/done"

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you want to check whether input `contains` "/done" rather than input `equals` "/done".

Comment: whether the use types `/done` or is it part of a larger string

Comment: Do you actually enter "/done" on its own line?

Comment: John - yes, you're right, contains would work rather than equals. Would you put that within the while of the do-while loop?? .. Arun - user would have to input /done all at once within the string input. Not on it's own line - it could be on it's own line but it is not necessary. Just has to be "/done" together

Comment: Even if you call `contains` it means your program won't break until the user hits the enter key. So I could type "blah blah /done blah blah<enter>" Is that what you want?

Comment: I forgot to mention that part. If you press enter key after typing /done within the string, the program WILL terminate. If you press enter key without /done anywhere in the string/line, then it simply moves you to new line in eclipse console and continues user string input on a new line. I hope that clears it up a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
         Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
         String input = "";
         String[] parts;
         System.out.println("Enter your string: ");
         while (true){
             input=s.nextLine();
            if (input.contains("/done")){
            parts=input.split("/done");
            //Use parts[0] to do any processing you want with the part of the string entered before /done in that line
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work fine

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    System.out.println("Enter your string: ");
        do {
        input = scanner.nextLine();
    } while (!input.contains("/done"));
    System.out.print("Rest of program here..");
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, instead of `equals`, use `contains`.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
System.out.println("Enter your string: ");

do {
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Rest of program here..");
}

while (!input.contains("/done"));
```